# Convert Json to an object in Android with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON array with a lot of entries and want to deserialize each check into a single object with gson. My problem is to find the proper object structure for it.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Client>>(){}.getType();
List<Client> clients = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "client": "client1",
        "check": {
            "handle": true,
            "standalone": false,
            "interval": 60,
            "refresh": 3600,
            "dependencies": [
                "keepalive"
            ],
            "command": "xxx",
            "occurrences": 1,
            "subscribers": [
                "xxx"
            ],
            "aggregate": false,
            "subdue": {
                "at": "handler",
                "begin": "6PM ICT",
                "end": "9AM ICT"
            },
            "name": "xxx",
            "issued": 1437922960,
            "executed": 1437922960,
            "duration": 0.148,
            "output": "xxx",
            "status": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "client": "client1",
        "check": {
            "thresholds": {
                "warning": 120,
                "critical": 180
            },
            "handler": "keepalive",
            "name": "keepalive",
            "issued": 1437922959,
            "executed": 1437922959,
            "output": "Keepalive sent from client 13 seconds ago",
            "status": 0
        }
    }, ....
]
```

I tried the object  below but it didnt work, it just gets `String client` but nothing from the Check class.

```
public class Check {
    public Boolean handle;
    public Boolean standaloone;
    public int interval;
    public int refresh;
    public String[] dependencies;
    public String commmand;
    public int occurrences;
    public String[] subscribers;
    public Boolean aggregate;
    public String[] subdue;
    public String name;
    public int issued;
    public int executed;
    public float duration;
    public String output;
    public int status;
}

public class Client {
    public String client;
    public Check check;
}
```

Comment: It seems that everything is ok. `name` and `issued` are at the same depth so if `name` is accessible then `issued` should be also as all other fields.

Comment: I needed to be more precise, its just gets public String client but nothing from the check class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the annotation like this to use GSON

```
public class Client {
        @SerializedName("client")
        public String client;

        @SerializedName("check")
        public Check check;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we check your json from http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ we see that "subdue" is not a String Array. It's an object.

So you need a class like:

```
public class Subdue {
    public String at;
    public String begin;
    public String end;
}
```

and modify your Check Class like:

```
public class Check {
    public Boolean handle;
    public Boolean standaloone;
    public int interval;
    public int refresh;
    public String[] dependencies;
    public String commmand;
    public int occurrences;
    public String[] subscribers;
    public Boolean aggregate;
    public Subdue subdue;
    public String name;
    public int issued;
    public int executed;
    public float duration;
    public String output;
    public int status;
}
```

I couldn't see any other problems. I hope this'll help you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation needs to be added to make GSON

eg: Add @SerializedName("client") before declaring the string client

```
@SerializedName("client")
public String client;
```

Instead of writing code repeatedly, you can do these in one go. check this - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/