# How to return updated JSON to server in android

Tags: android, json

I am creating an app in which I'm using `JSON`. I want to return same `JSON` to server after updated in following `JSON`.

```
[{
            "u1": "abc",
            "u2": "xyz",
            "u3": "From",
            "u4": "0",

}, {
            "u1": "abcd",
            "u2": "wxyz",
            "u3": "to",
            "u4": "0",

}, {
            "u1": "abcde",
            "u2": "vwxyz",
            "u3": "other",
            "u4": "0",

}]
```

I am using volley lib to send data on server like this..

```
 private void makeJsonObjDataLAS() {


    JSONObject jsonparam = new JSONObject();
        jsonparam.put("Empid", LAempid);
        jsonparam.put("UserType", usertype);
        jsonparam.put("FirstReq", 0);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.KEY_URL, jsonparam,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonReq = response.getJSONObject("Response");                            
                        if (jsonReq.getString("Code").equals("200")) {
                            status  = jsonReq.getString("Status");
                            message  = jsonReq.getString("Msg");
                            pDialog.dismiss();

                        }  

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                       pDialog.dismiss();                         

                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){                              
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    //jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            Constants.TIME_OUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    // app.AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,tag_json_obj);

}
```

I want to update value in (UserVal and UserTid) and send to server how is it possible please tell me.

Comment: Create POJO class and use GSON to convert your response. then update the values which ever you want and post the same to server by PoJO.toString();

Comment: Simple use method json object to gson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638798/convert-json-to-an-object-in-android-with-gson

Comment: just **make an JSONObject** again and post it to server by using **json.toString()** method

Comment: Please give me an example  related to this..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235341/how-to-create-json-object-using-com-google-gson-class/45235660#45235660

Comment: please provide example with GSON parsing..

Comment: which library are u using? volley or retrofit??

Comment: i m using volley library  for parsing data

Comment: Did u get the answer?

Comment: please tell me how to send data (String) to server after updation using volley

Answer (score 0):

try this just make an `JSONObject` again and post it to server by using `json.toString()` method  like this

```
Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
            try {

                // Convert your  object to JSON usin Gson like this
               JSONObject request;

               // convert your model class in to json object like this
               DataModel model= new DataModel();
               Gson gson = new Gson();
               String jsonString = gson.toJson(model);

                try {
                   request = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // convert json object to string
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(request);
                // call here your service and pass parameter
                new SendDeviceDetails.execute("your service url", json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i three values in using  postData.put("Key", "value");..my value depend on json. i am getting 3 object in json so i want  update value  in all three object . how should i do please tell me..

Comment: i am using volley lib to send the data to server like this

Comment: JSONObject jsonparam = new JSONObject();
            jsonparam.put("Empid", LAempid);
            jsonparam.put("UserType", usertype);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.KEY_URL, jsonparam,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

Comment: i have added code in question please see in question

Comment: @AlishaSharma now just pass your converted json String in volley las a paramter to your server

Answer (score 0):

**1. Convert your response into corresponding model class using gson or other supported libraries.**

```
List<Model> modelList = new Gson().fromJson(response,new TypeToken<List<Model>>);
```

**2.Update the values, based on your requirement.**

```
for(Model model : modelList ){
model.displayName = "your_values"; //just an example
}
```

**3.Convert the model object back into json**

```
String jsonBody = new Gson().toJson(model);
```

4.**Send that json to the server.**`

```
WebServiceRequest request = new WebServiceRequest(url,
Request.Method.POST,  new HashMap<String, String>(), jsonBody, this, this); // add listeners in your activity or fragment
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
request.setRetryPolicy(policy);
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);
```

Comment: here i m using post method to send data

Comment: please   tell one thing more ...i have three string variable those contains value so, how to set those varabile in (model.displayName = "str1") all update in different object as seen json

Comment: with different value in  "DisplayName"

Comment: how to replace "your_values" with string1 ,string2,string3.........stringn

Comment: put your values in string array or list . map and update .

Comment: like this...for(Model model : modelList ){
model.displayName = String[]; 
} which  paramets should i passed inString[ parameter]

Comment: are you a beginner ?

Comment: yes..i  m beginner with this..please tell me only parameters should i passed in it..

Comment: 1.if you want to update all the values make sure both string value list and response list are of equal size.
a)if they have equal size you can assign it like this model.displayName = valueArray[i];i++.
2.if you only want to update only specific value then based on that you have to put your own logic.

Comment: i am getting json body in peices.how to combine jsonbodies in json array  and send to server..